# Ubuntu Uninstall all Python's and Pip's

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'm using Ubuntu Mate on a Raspberry Pi and want to uninstall all existing Python and Pip versions so that I can install only **Python 3.8.3** and **pip 20.1.1** because at the moment it's really confusing. I just want to type python something or pip install something and those versions to be used so i think the best way would be to uninstall them all and simply install the 2 versions I need.

I tried to run `sudo apt-get remove --purge python` but that didn't seem to have worked.

Comment: It's advised not to do that, it might break the operating system you can have multiple version's of python interpreter installed & use ``virtual env``.

Comment: Honestly by running that you've probably already broken stuff pretty bad. I would clean install the OS, set up `virtualenvwrapper`, clone `pyenv` in `/usr/local/lib` and install `3.8.3`, and make a virtualenv from that Python executable. Then you can easily install the version of pip you want in the virtualenv, and install all the packages you want, and reset the virtualenv easily if you need to.